# Twincat HMI Data-binding Crash

Tags: visual-studio, twincat

Im relative new to Twincat HMI. And when i try to "create data binding.." for the text under the common section of  a Textbox, the whole TcXaeShell Crashes. I get no notification on what causes the crash. Anyone have an idea?

I am trying to make a usercontrol easily reuse the design in other contents.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative option, were i can make a custom binding under "show events" section, instead of binding directly with the text under the common section. Worked without crashing.